# AngularJS | Passing directive's name as an attribute to another directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, popup

In my markup I have a container, and two buttons inside of it. Each button opens the same popup window but with different content. Container and buttons are made with directives and the popup - with service. The HTML:

```
<div my-container>
    <my-button ng-click="openPopup()" popupContent="<popup-content1></popup-content1>"></my-button>
    <my-button ng-click="openPopup()" popupContent="<popup-content2></popup-content1>"></my-button>
    <my-popup></my-popup>
</div>
```

As you can see I try to add some content to the popup window as an attribute and the value of the attribute is the name of a directive that has to be inserted in the DOM. 
First, I get the attributes in my-button directive:

```
//...
link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
    scope.openPopup()(true, attrs.popupContent);
}
//...
```

Then I pass the value of the attribute to my-container directive's controller to scope:

```
//...
$scope.openPopup = function(msg, content) {
    //...
    $scope.popupContent = content;
};
```

And after that I try to get the attribute's value in the popup's template:

```
<header> .... </header> 
<ng-transclude>{{ popupContent }}</ng-transclude>
<footer> ... </footer>
```

So, the problem is that I got strings like

```
<popup-content1></popup-content1>
```

in my popup instead of the real content like "Lorem ipsum...." (which is in my popup-content1 and popup-content2 directives templates).

How can I get the 'real' content into my popup?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Concept is all wrong. Pass variable to attribute and use isolated scope to evaluate. Also what you are showing wouldn't need `ng-transclude`. Is content just text or is it html?

Comment: @charlietfl, thanks for your answer. Yes, my content for the popup is html. Why don't I need ng-transclude? I used it to show my content but manually not programmatically. From where should I pass a variable and where to use isolated scope? Could you, please, give more details?

Comment: use isolated scope and then inside directive use `ng-bind-html`. Will need to make sure you include `ngSanitize` in app dependencies

Comment: example : https://thinkster.io/egghead/isolate-scope-at

Comment: I think that `ng-bind-html` it not enough you need to compile the directive first.

Comment: @charlietfl, thank you for your advice, but could you, please, maybe give some code examples? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Zaki, thank you for the link, but it seems this is not what I ask about...

Comment: @jcubic, thank you for the advice. Could you, please, give example how to use compile in my case? To which directive? As I have five of them

Comment: Can you create [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/]) that I can work with?

Comment: @jcubic, sure! But is it OK if it will be in 3-4 hours?

Comment: Sure, but remember to mention me so I have notification from SO.

Comment: @jcubic, please, see my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ms_Smith/vxam0dva/10/). But I can't make the buttons to show up - can't add angular properly, could you please help?

Comment: I was not able to make compile work, PS: you need to add `<body ng-app="myApp">`

Comment: @jcubic, please, see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Ms_Smith/bs3b98pq/1/), hope this time it'l work